# Compare value of int

Tags: c#, operators, int

How can I test if value of int is for example 1,2,4 or 5? I thought i could do something like this but apparently not.

```
if(someInt == (1||2||4||5))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
if ((new[] {1,2,4,5}).Contains(someInt))
```

Comment: You can make it a bit cleaner by doing: `if(Enumerable.Range(1,5).Contains(someInt))`

Comment: @Filip that's cleaner but has a different meaning

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, The only difference is that it's more simple of he wants to find the number in an array for 200 ints counting from 1 to 200. Otherwise you might see people manually adding 200 ints to an array initialization.

Comment: This shouldn't be used in a time constrained application. A quick performance measure using a loop with 10,000,000 iterations yields: `linq`-solution(7,838s); `if`-solution(0.0489s); `switch`-solution((0.0285s)

Comment: @filip the list is 1, 2, 4, 5

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, *doh* I missed that :).

Comment: @FrankBollack, Did you try with a Release Build?

Comment: @FilipEkberg: The figures where in deed from a debug build, but on a release build, they aren't much different: linq-solution(7.0471s); if-solution(0.026s); switch-solution(0.022s)

Comment: @FilipEkberg: ...interestingly the linq-solution in an x64 release build performs in 1.841s on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

Write an extension method

```
static class MiscExtensions
{
    static bool EqualToAny<T>(this T i, params T[] items)
    {
        return items.Any(x => x.Equals(i));
    }
}
```

And use it like so

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myNumber = 5;
        if (myNumber.EqualToAny(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your `if` statement like this

```
if (someInt==1 || someInt==2 || someInt==4 || someInt==4)
```

Or you could use a `switch` statement

```
switch (someInt)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

---

Breaking down your attempted code is quite interesting. You wrote:

```
if(someInt == (1||2||4||5))
```

I guess in your head you read it as, *if someInt equals 1 or 2 or 4 or 5*. And if computers behaved like humans then this would work. But we all know that computers don't behave like that!

The `==` equality operator, a binary operator, returns `true` when its two operands are equal. So that means, in your version, if it compiled, you would need `someInt` to be equal to `(1||2||4||5)`. And for that to even be meaningful, we would need `(1||2||4||5)` to evaluate to a single value, instead of producing a compile error. And, if it did evaluate to a single value, then it could not have the meaning which you want. Because you want the test to return true when `someInt` is equal to one of four candidate values.

The bottom line is that `==` tests for exact equality between precisely two values.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use:

```
switch(someInt)
{
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 4:
   case 5:
      DoYourStuff();
      break;
}
```

Comment: +1 - I was just typing the exact same solution when I saw that there were new answers available :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of.

Or all the comparisons.

```
if (someInt == 1 || someInt == 2 || someInt == 4 || someInt == 5) {

}
```

Or for a more flexible solution see if someInt is in an array.

```
if (Array.BinarySearch(new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 }, someInt ) != -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. Instead use:

```
if(someInt == 1 || someInt == 2 || someInt == 4 || someInt == 5)
```

Or also you could use something like this:

```
if((new List<int>() {1,2,4,5}).Contains(someInt) == true)
```

Comment: take note of the fact that the OP did not include `3` as acceptable in his criteria

Comment: @ErikPhilips I prefer to always specify the "== true" or "== false" segment. Human error possibility is reduced by doing so, I've learned. The compiler don't mind, neither the proccesor and the code makes more sense.